# very simple OSX bash script: echo gives no output

Tags: macos, bash

I'm running OSX 10.6, and I have this very simple script in a file "hi.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"
```

I've already run "chmod +x hi.sh".  Now, I've tried both of the following:

```
$ ./hi.sh
$ bash hi.sh
```

and neither outputs "hi".  What could be the problem?

Comment: are you sure of your bash path? do a "which bash" also try #!/bin/sh

Comment: "which bash" gives "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It could be that you used an editor that defaults to `\r` as line separator, which was the separator used under classic (pre OS X) MacOS. Try `wc -l hi.sh`; if you get 0 lines, then it's a line ending problem. Your script would then be just a single comment line, which would of course do nothing.

Comment: Indeed, it's showing 0 lines.  I'm using TextWrangler to edit, and I've got it set to use UNIX line endings...  Is there a surefire way to convert line endings to UNIX?

Comment: I'm not a regular user of TextWrangler, but it should be able to convert the line endings. Be sure that you have it "convert" to Unix line breaks, not just have it "use" them, which will probably leave the file unchanged.

Comment: @Bavarious As you might guess, this is something I encountered before. It took quite a while to realize what the problem was - not easily forgotten!

Comment: I definitely have my editor set to translate to Unix line endings now, but still wc shows 0 lines...are there any commands that can ensure I'm using Unix endings?

Comment: @maackle I'm not at my Mac right now to try it out, but I took a look through the TextWrangler users' manual http://pine.barebones.com/manual/TextWrangler_User_Manual.pdf . Take a look at pp. 39-40: it looks like you can have TW "Translate line breaks" in the Open dialog, then just re-save the script.

Comment: @maackle: I've now had a chance to see how to change the line endings in TextWrangler. In the status bar at the bottom of a TextWrangler window, there is a popup menu that lets you select the type of line break. Choose "Unix (LF)" and save. If you need to change a lot of files, definitely follow Dennis Williamson's lead and use a shell script.

Comment: @Michael J:  That was it!  Thanks so much for your great eyes and intuition.